# Integrate $\sin^n{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you integrate:

$$\int(\sin^n{x}) dx$$

The link to WolframAlpha : ([Integration Answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin%5En))

No definite limits...

What is that hypergeometric function in that answer. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Hover over the text "hypergeometric function" on WA and it leads you to [its definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: @John Can i have a simpler definition?

Comment: Before worrying (if ever) about hypergeometric functions, one should obtain a reduction formula,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using binomial series ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)), we have:
$$(1-\cos^2x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} = 1 - \frac{n-1}{2}\cos^2x + \frac{n-1}{2}\frac{n-3}{4}\cos^4x-\ldots. $$

Then:

$$ \int\sin^nx dx = \int\sin x (1-\cos^2x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} dx $$
$$ = \int\sin x \left(1 - \frac{n-1}{2}\cos^2x + \frac{n-1}{2}\frac{n-3}{4}\cos^4x-\ldots\right) dx $$
$$ = \int \left(\sin x  + \frac{1-n}{2}\cos^2x \sin x+ \frac{1-n}{2}\frac{3-n}{4}\cos^4x\sin x -\ldots\right) dx $$
$$ = -\cos x -  \frac{1-n}{2}\cos^3x/3 - \frac{1-n}{2}\frac{3-n}{4}\cos^5x/5 -\ldots$$
$$ = -\cos x \cdot({\rm hypergeometric \; series}).$$

Comment: Can we convert sin(x) to exponential terms to make it (maybe ) easier?

Comment: Not sure. You can try. Binomial series is pretty powerful and clean (if you accept it). Cheers :). Also, you should pursue @AndréNicolas reduction suggestion and prove, using integration by parts, that: $I_n = -1/n\sin^{n-1}\cos x+(n-1)/nI_{n-2}$, where $I_n$ is the integral.

Comment: Why is it often said that $\int \sqrt{\sin{(x)}}$ cannot be done because in that case $n=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and according to your method we should be able to do it.... Also in WolframAlpha they use some special function...